# Login Page will not open profile activity

Tags: java, android

After a user registers in the signup activity page I want them to be able to press the login button in the login page and then for the app to go to a profile activity page.  However, the app crashes after typing in the username and password and pressing the login button in the login page. Here is the sets of codes and this first set is the Login Page code in "LoginPageActivity.java" activity.

```
package com.example.xxxx.safetyxxxxxxx;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;



public class LoginPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    EditText editTextEmail, editTextPassword;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_page);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        editTextEmail = findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

    findViewById(R.id.textViewSignUp).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin).setOnClickListener(this);

}

private void userLogin(){

    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if(email.isEmpty()){
        editTextEmail.setError("Email is required");
        editTextEmail.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
        editTextEmail.setError("Please enter a valid email");
        editTextEmail.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if(password.isEmpty()){
        editTextPassword.setError("Password is required");
        editTextPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if(password.length()<6){
        editTextPassword.setError("Minimum length of password should be 6");
        editTextPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginPageActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.textViewSignUp:

                    startActivity(new Intent(this, SignUpActivity.class));

                    break;

                case R.id.buttonLogin:
                    userLogin();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the profile activity called "ProfileActivity.java"

```
package com.example.xxxx.safetyxxxxxxx;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    }
}
```

Here is the android manifest code.  I have tried many different variations of declaring the ProfileActivity class in this manifest based on research and previous issues in the past with the same logcat error.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.xxxx.safetyxxxxxxx">

    <application
        android:name=".Database"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginPageActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"/>
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SignUpActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">

    </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the logcat error

```
12-02 12:04:56.008 2644-2644/com.example.xxxx.safetyxxxxxxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.xxxx.safetyxxxxxxx, PID: 2644
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.xxxx.safetyxxxxxxx/com.example.xxxx.safetyxxxxxxx.ProfileActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1933)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1616)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4488)
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4446)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:720)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4807)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4775)
    at com.example.xxxx.safetyxxxxxxx.LoginPageActivity$1.onComplete(LoginPageActivity.java:79)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source:23)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Finally in case it is needed here is the loginpage layout code called "activity_login_page.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LoginPageActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Hi, Welcome to Safety xxxxxxx Please Login or Signup"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonLogin"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.66"></TextView>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Login"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.87" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
        android:layout_width="346dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextPassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.95" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
        android:layout_width="346dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint=" Password"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonLogin"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.87" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="219dp"
        android:layout_height="229dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextEmail"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.233"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/safetyxxx" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSignUp"
        android:layout_width="345dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Do Not Have An Account?  Click Here"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonLogin" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.xxxx.safetyxxxxxxx/com.example.xxxx.safetyxxxxxxx.ProfileActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Comment: Please research your problem before putting it here. lot of resources available to find solution of this question on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries all I needed to do was press the rebuild project button.  It worked perfectly after that.

Thanks for all that tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly said in the fatal message:                                                                               android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.xxxx.safetyxxxxxxx/com.example.xxxx.safetyxxxxxxx.ProfileActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

So, you have mess in the manifest file: please try to remove package name from the definitions of activities:e.g stings like "activity android:name="com.example.xxxx.safetyxxxxxxx.LoginPageActivity" should be changed to "activity android:name=".LoginPageActivity"

Best regards!

Comment: Thanks for your help but I tried that but it didn't work.

        <activity android:name=".LoginPageActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"/>
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SignUpActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>
    </application>

Comment: Is it still crashing? Can you please post new logcat?

Comment: still crashing.  posted updated logcat, which I don't think anything changed.  ill throw in the updated manifest too

Answer (score 0):

You might give this a shot.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.xxxx.safetyxxxxxxx">

    <application
        android:name=".Database"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginPageActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SignUpActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

This may not help but I would personally give it a shot myself.